# ios merging two video,the above is a black background

Tags: ios

How can I remove the black background？What's the useful framework?AVAnimator can do it? http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVRender

Comment: Well, I am not sure why you posted a link to AVAnimator in your question. The most simple approach is to process your video on the desktop and create a series of PNG images with an alpha channel. That will produce images that you can compose in layers on your iOS device, but for better performance you will likely want a better solution. Doing background replacement can work for specific videos where you control the source, but you will likely find it easier to just remove the background on your desktop and then export in a known format that supports an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more information. What have you tried ? What do you exactly want to achieve. 
Here are some links that should get you started if i understand your needs correctly.

[Ray Wenderlich Merging Videos](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

I think the key class you should have a look at is: **AVMutableComposition**

Comment: [meipai](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mei-pai-10miao-ye-neng-pai/id847334708?mt=8) this is my expect effect